# Printing Multiples Between a Positive Integer and a Max Positive Integer

Tags: java, loops

For this program, I'm trying to print the multiples from "n" to a "max". The part I'm having trouble with is how to make a proper loop that prints these numbers.

Sample Input:

n=3 max=20

Sample output:

3

6

9

12

15

18

```
public class Average {
    public static void printMultiples(int n, int max) {

        while (n<=max) {
        for (int i=1;;i++) {
            System.out.println(n*i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer:")
        int n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a maximum positive integer:")
        int max = s.nextInt();
        printMultiples(n,max);
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

  public static void printMultiples(int n, int max) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
      if (i % n == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer:");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a maximum positive integer:");
    int max = s.nextInt();
    printMultiples(n, max);
  }
}
```

Or using Java 8 Lambda:

```
  public static void printMultiples(int n, int max) {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, max).filter(i -> i % n == 0).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

Comment: I need to print the multiples, so like 3x1=3, 3x2=6, and so forth until it gets to the max.

Comment: @HydratedDeer So for n=3 max=20 output should be 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18?

Comment: @HydratedDeer i've updated my answer with full code example

Comment: My bad! I tested your code wrong, but it works great. Thank you!